# How do I make Rails log timestamps in UTC timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

How do I make Rails print the log timestamps in UTC instead of localtime? It currently prints

```
Started GET "/" for 190.176.185.42 at 2013-08-21 18:27:56 -0400
```

This will make it easier to find errors reported by users. I saw this http://apidock.com/rails/Logger and tried

#### production.rb

```
  Rails.logger.datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"
```

but it gave an error

```
undefined method `datetime_format=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I don't think just setting the format will work. I think I need to actually convert the time into UTC first.

Rails 3.2.14.

Comment: The problem is that your logger is `nil`. Why is that?

Comment: I don't know. It is in production.rb. Maybe it's not initialized yet. Where should I place that line? Is that the correct line to use?

Comment: It probably is, try doing `Rails.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new('wherever_the_log_goes.log')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line of log is generated by [`started_request_message`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.14/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb#L38). It seems hard to change it because it is hard coded to use the default format. Maybe you have to override this method for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it worked! Using Yanhao's info, at the bottom of production.rb,

```
Rails::Rack::Logger.class_eval do
  # Override logging to spit out UTC time to easier find user reported errors
  # https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.14/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb#L38
  def started_request_message(request)
    'Started %s "%s" for %s at %s' % [
      request.request_method,
      request.filtered_path,
      request.ip,
      Time.now.utc ]
  end
end
```